# Understanding a proof of the multiplication operator version of the spectral theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

At the moment I am trying to understand the proof of the multiplication operator version of the spectral theorem in "Operator Theoretic Aspects of Ergodic Theory" by Eisner, Farkas, Haase and Nagel ([https://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/~eisner/book-EFHN.pdf](https://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/%7Eeisner/book-EFHN.pdf)) in Chapter 18.

In the proof they use the Gelfand-Naimark Theorem they explain earlier in the book. I have a few questions about the proof, since it is really short and has (for a student with not super much knowledge in functional analysis) not enough explanations to understand all the different steps...

My first question is about the isomorphisms in the proof below. I assume the first one comes from Gelfand-Naimark but I do not really understand how it works with this cyclic subspaces as it is explained above the proof. I also don't know why $\bigoplus_\alpha L^2(K, \mu_{x_\alpha}) \cong L^2(\bigcup_\alpha K_\alpha, \bigoplus_\alpha \mu_{x_\alpha})$ holds.

And as a bigger question: I also do not see where the assumptions such as the operator being bounded and normal are needed in the proof.

[image]

Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: I don't like to click links. Can you fix your post so that it is self-contained?

Comment: While QuantumSpace is quite right about self contained posts, on the other hand I am very grateful to any and all users who link educational resources! Thank you for the book

Comment: @QuantumSpace I absolutely understand, i am sorry! do you mean i should just copy the theorem and its proof into the question by writing it down? Or is there any other way to do it? I am afraid that just copying theorem and proof does not contain all the informations, since a lot of things that are needed are explained on the pages before.

Comment: @putti.123 No worries! Leave the link, but at least post an image of the theorem and its proof in your post and indicate which parts are not clear to you.

Comment: @QuantumSpace did that! thanks:)

Comment: @putti.123 Start by showing the isomorphism $L^2(\bigcup_\alpha X_\alpha, \bigoplus_\alpha \mu_\alpha) \cong \bigoplus_\alpha L^2(X_\alpha, \mu_\alpha)$. You can construct two obvious maps from set to the other and show that these are mutually inverses.